# where does Application Pool get stored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, application-pool

if created application pool in IIS where does it get stored physically. I mean in which file?

I have HDD which was having application pool and applications on IIS working. but after it crashed I had connected it to another computer as an external HDD. I would like to create the same application pools and applications but don't know where should I search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS stores configuration of web sites, applications and pools in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`.